# Como puedo actualizar datos de un select input multiple

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo problema (no se como hacer un UPDATE) a la hora de actulizar la ficha del alumno ya que solo me cambia el nombre y imagen del alumno, y lo que quiero hacer es añadir o quitar los cursos en el que esta inscrito desde un select multiple.

Esta es una captura del archivo edit:

http://127.0.0.1/php/edit_student.php?id=2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Alumnos

```
---------------------------------------------
- student_id - student_name - student_image -
---------------------------------------------
-          1 - Ana          - avatar.jpg    -
-          2 - David        - avatar.jpg    -
-          3 - Jasmine      - avatar.jpg    -
---------------------------------------------
```

Tabla Cursos

```
-------------------------------------------
- course_id - course_title - course_image -
-------------------------------------------
-         7 - Photoshop    - image.jpg    -
-         8 - Cinema 4D    - image.jpg    -
-         9 - Idesign      - image.jpg    -
-        10 - Illustrator  - image.jpg    -
-------------------------------------------
```

Tabla Alumnos_Cursos

```
----------------------------------------------
students_courses_id - course_id - student_id - 
----------------------------------------------
-         1         -      7    -       1   
-         2         -      8    -       2   
-         3         -      9    -       2   
-         4         -      10   -       3   
-         5         -      8    -       1   
----------------------------------------------
```

Mi codigo

```
$connect = connect($database);
if(!$connect){
    header ('Location: ' . SITE_URL . '/controller/error.php');
    }
```

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

```
$course_id = $_POST['course_id'];

$student_id = cleardata($_POST['student_id']);
$student_name = cleardata($_POST['student_name']);
$student_image_save = $_POST['student_image_save'];
$student_image = $_FILES['student_image'];

if (empty($student_image['name'])) {
    $student_image = $student_image_save;
} else{
    $student_image_upload = '../' . $items_config['images_folder'] . $_FILES['student_image']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['student_image']['tmp_name'], $student_image_upload);
    $student_image = $_FILES['student_image']['name'];
}
```

$statment = $connect->prepare(
    'UPDATE students SET student_name = :student_name, student_image = :student_image WHERE student_id = :student_id'
    );

$statment->execute(array(

        ':student_name' => $student_name,
        ':student_image' => $student_image,
        ':student_id' => $student_id

        ));

$statment = $connect->prepare( 'UPDATE students_courses SET course_id = :course_id WHERE student_id ='.$student_id) ;
$statment->execute();

Comment: alguien me puede ayudar ?!

Comment: Hola puedes agregar el código PHP donde realizas la consulta SQL (donde haces el update)... Saludos

Comment: Hola @AlfonsoCarrasco te lo adjunto en el pastebin: http://pastebin.com/SXwdYhVC

Comment: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

 $student_id = cleardata($_POST['student_id']);
 $student_name = cleardata($_POST['student_name']);
 }


$statment = $connect->prepare(
 'UPDATE students SET student_name = :student_name WHERE student_id = :student_id'
 );

$statment->execute(array(

  ':student_name' => $student_name,
  ':student_id' => $student_id

  ));

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes de hacer es borrar todos los cursos que tenga el alumno con su id, así quedará vacía tu base de datos, y seguido ejecutas un insert de todos los cursos que se haya inscrito, esto lo puedes hacer enviando un post con los datos del id del curso en una cadena separada por espacios o comas y con el método explode sacas el array y lo recorres con un foreach para insertar como guía te dejo este pseudocodigo:

```
//Aqui tu consulta para borrar todos los cursos del alumno

//Usas el explode para que te de un array
$cursos = "curso1,curso2,curso3";
$lista_cursos = explode(",", $cursos);

    foreach ($lista_cursos as $idcurso) {
    //aqui preparas tu consulta para insertar por un curso a la vez
        $statment = $connect->prepare( 'INSERT') ;
        $statment->execute();
    }
```